# Paragraph space after section

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Maybe this will sound stupid as I'm still a bit noob in LaTeX. I'm writing a quick report and I'm not concerned with formatting right now but there is something that is bothering me. I've noticed that after using `\section{Name of section}` the 1st paragraph does no show any space at the begging while all the other paragraphs show a space at the begging. I've tried to insert a empty line between the `\section{Name of section}` and the text but does not change.

Is there an easy workaround this? And is there any reason for this 1st paragraph not starting with a space?

Comment: `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

Comment: In some languages (e.g. spanish) has been common typography (not orthography) indent also the first paragraph, but the logic of indentation is highlight  the beginning of a paragraph. However,  after a title is absolutely clear where it is, so indentation have not sense at all. Moreover, indentation of first paragraph  could left a perception of misaligned text, specially if the indentation if excessive (or too small).